# Finding intersection of two contour plots in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, contour

I was wondering if anyone could give me a clue on finding the intersection of two contour plots? Ideally it would take pair of contours, then return the coordinate of the intersections

```
Z1 = somefunction
Z2 = somefunction1
Z3 = somefunction2
xlist = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
ylist = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist)
figtest = plt.figure()
axtest = figtest.add_subplot( 111 )
axtest.contour(X,Y,Z1,[1],colors='green', linewidths=4)
axtest.contour(X,Y,Z2,[1],colors='orange', linewidths=4)
axtest.contour(X,Y,Z3,[1],colors='blue',linewidths=4)                  
axtest.set_xlim([0, 9])
axtest.set_ylim([0, 9])
axtest.legend()
axtest.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

So far I tried, extracting the coordinate that makes up the contour and try to find the intersection of the arrays of both contours, but it returns an empty array, I assume since there isn't an exact coordinate which is a member of both arrays

Edit:

I did it. Here's how:

```
from shapely import geometry

def findIntersection(contour1,contour2):
  p1 = contour1.collections[0].get_paths()[0]
  v1 = p1.vertices

  p2 = contour2.collections[0].get_paths()[0]
  v2 = p2.vertices

  poly1 = geometry.LineString(v1)
  poly2 = geometry.LineString(v2)

  intersection = poly1.intersection(poly2)

  return intersection

c1 = axtest.contour(X,Y,Z1,[1],colors='green', linewidths=4)
c2 = axtest.contour(X,Y,Z2,[1],colors='orange', linewidths=4)

intersection_example = findIntersection(c1,c2)
```

where coordinates can be accessed by

```
intersection_example.x ##get x points
intersection_example.y ##get y points
list(intersection_example.coords)  ## get in [x,y] formatting
```

hope it helps someone

Comment: I'd extract the coordinates into shapely objects, and let shapely find the intersection

Comment: Can you provide the code for finding the intersection ?

Comment: @PaulH I did what you told me. But when I do `poly1 = geometry.Polygon(v1)` where `v1 = array_of_vertices`, and `print(poly1)`, somehow the first element on the array got appended back at the end. I guess it made sense since it's for polygon. So when I do `poly1.intersection(poly2)`, I got an error `TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point`, am I using the right function?

Comment: @blueblood I would suggest to [edit] the question to include a [mcve] of the code that produces this problem. Once there is some code to work with, it's much easier to help.

Comment: never mind, I reread the documentation, noticed I should be using LineString instead of Polygon. It works! Thanks! @PaulH

Comment: @CristianoAraujo see my answer above, hope it helps!

Comment: @blueblood You may answer your own question. This has several advantages: 1. The question retains the Q&A style of this site, 2. It makes it easier for other people to find the solution to the problem, 3. The question does not stay in the list of unanswered questions, 4. You may even gain reputation from people upvoting the answer.